# How to group same values in column in R

Tags: r, vector

How to get index number in a Boolean vector? For instance, my vector looks like this:

vector = (TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE)

How to get index number for all TRUEs? vector["TRUE"] doesn't work.

Comment: `which(vector==TRUE)`

Comment: `which(vector)` is sufficient

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `which` function (type `?which`):

```
> my.vec <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
> which(my.vec)
> [1] 1 4
```